$R$-recursion for unsigned Genocchi numbers (of first kind) of even index

Let $G_n$ be A036968 (i.e., Genocchi numbers). Here
$$
\frac{2t}{1+e^t}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}G_n\frac{t^n}{n!}.
$$
Also
$$
t\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n G_{2n}\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
$$
Let
$$
R(n, q) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q+1}\binom{q+2}{j}R(n-1, j), \\
R(0, q) = 1.
$$

I conjecture that
$$
R(n, 0) = (-1)^n G_{2(n+2)}.
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
upto1(n) = my(v1, v2, v3, v4); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, 1); v2 = v1; v3 = vector(n + 1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; v4 = vector(n+2, i, vector(i, j, j==1 || i==j)); for(i=2, n+2, for(j=2, i-1, v4[i][j] = v4[i-1][j] + v4[i-1][j-1])); for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q + 1] = sum(j=0, q+1, v4[q+3][j+1]*v1[j + 1])); v1 = v2; v3[i + 1] = v1[1]); v3
upto2(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n+1, i, i++; 2*(-1)^i*(1 - 4^i)*bernfrac(2*i))
test(n) = upto1(n) == upto2(n)

Is there a way to prove it?

I’m not sure what the motivation for these questions is, but you should be able to prove it using generating functions just like your previous question.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475744/r-recursion-for-fibonacci-numbers-using-signed-catalan-numbers/475769

Where is binomial coefficient $\binom{q+2}j$ in your PARI/GP code?

@AaronBergman, thank you for comment! I am also grateful to you for the answer to my previous question. Could you also answer this one? By the way, I have a lot of questions about $R$-recursions.

@MaxAlekseyev, thank you for comment! It is v4[q+3][j+1].

@Notamathematician: why not just binomial(q+2,j) ?

@MaxAlekseyev, the same coefficients are called several times.

@Notamathematician: You won't notice any difference on small numbers, but your code lacks readability.

From the recurrence it follows that the generating function $F(x,y) := \sum_{n,k\geq 0} R(n,k) \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \frac{y^k}{k!}$ satisfies a neat PDE:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} F(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}(e^y-1)F(x,y)$$
with the boundary conditions $F(0,y)=e^y$ and $F_x(0,y)=0$. The question is then equivalent to showing that
$$F(x,0) = \frac{\partial^4}{\partial^4 x} x\tan(\tfrac{x}2).$$
Unfortunately, the "standard" route of solving this PDE and plugging in $y=0$ in the solution seems to be infeasible here. At least both Mathematica and Maple fail to solve this PDE. So, we need to take another route.

Let's focus on generating functions for each row:
$$G_n(y) := \sum_{k\geq 0} R(n,k) \frac{y^k}{k!}.$$
We have $G_0(y) = e^y$ and for $n\geq1$,
$$G_{n+1}(y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}(e^y-1)G_n(y).$$
Clearly, $G_n(y)$ represents a polynomial of degree $n+1$ in $e^y$, and with a bit of effort we can derive the following formula for the coefficient of $e^{ky}$ in $G_n(y)$:
$$(-1)^{n+1-k} [z^{n+1}]\ \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{j^2z}{1-j^2z}.$$
It further implies that
\begin{split}
R(n,0) = G_n(0) &= (-1)^{n+1} [z^{n+1}] \sum_{k\geq 0} k!^2 (-z)^k \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1-j^2z} \\
&=(-1)^n [z^{n+2}] \sum_{k\geq 0} k!^2 (-z)^{k+1} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1-j^2z}.
\end{split}
The series in the right-hand side can be recognized as the generating function for Genocchi numbers listed in OEIS A001469:

O.g.f.: Sum_{n>=0} n!^2*(-x)^(n+1) / Product_{k=1..n} (1-k^2*x). - Paul D. Hanna, Jul 21 2011

I'm not sure what is the source of Hanna's formula, but the above analysis essentially shows that the question is equivalent to it.

I haven't checked the details but my guess is that Hanna's formula comes from expressing the Genocchi numbers in terms of central factorial numbers (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471918/closed-form-for-the-a110501-unsigned-genocchi-numbers-of-first-kind-of-even-i?rq=1) and then using the ordinary generating function for central factorial numbers, which can be found at https://oeis.org/A036969.
